# How to stack keyframes in CSS animation programmatically

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

I am trying to stack CSS keyframes (animation-delay) on the following and I am not sure how to do this programmatically?

```css
        .r1 {
          animation-name: move1;
          animation-delay: 0.5s;      
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }
 
        .r2 {
          animation-name: move1;
          animation-delay: 1.5s;      
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }
             .r3 {
          animation-name: move1;
          animation-delay: 2.5s;      
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in;
          animation-direction: normal;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }
 
        @keyframes move1 {
          to {
            transform: translateX(200px);
          }  
        }
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
<rect class="r1" x="10" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
    <rect class="r2" x="10" y="130" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
    <rect class="r3" x="10" y="240" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

The `animation-duration` is hardcoded for each class and the `animation-delay` is hardcoded for the first class, i.e.`r1`.

How can I pass on the delay for r2 and r3, such as

`r2 delay= r1 delay + r1 duration->0.5+1=1.5s`

and

`r3 delay= r2 delay + r2 duration ->1.5+1=2.5s`

Is there anything in javascript that gives `animation-duration` by class?

I tried doing this by [Element.getAnimations()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations) but I am not sure if there is anything that gives animation duration by class.

I don't want to do this manually as I have a lot of class in the svg.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does calc() work for your case?

Comment: I can try and let you know if you have calc solution

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()

Comment: How do I get the animation duration with calc in the current class for previous class

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set r class for your rects and I think this can help you:

```
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('svg rect');

for (let i = 1; i<blocks.length; i++) {
    const element = blocks[i];
  const prevElementStyles = getComputedStyle(blocks[i-1]);

  
  element.style.animationDelay = `${parseFloat(prevElementStyles.animationDelay) + parseFloat(prevElementStyles.animationDuration)}s`;
}
```

r class:

```
.r {
  animation-name: move1;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;      
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
<rect class="r" x="10" y="20" width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
    <rect class="r" x="10" y="130" width="100" height="100" fill="green"/>
    <rect class="r" x="10" y="240" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This looks good. But while I am trying to generate the delay with js and the above will work only when I am applying same animation to all r class. But in my case, I will be applying different animation to different class such as - r1 with m1(translateX), r2 with x2(rotate), r3 with q1(scale). Sorry for troubling you. I should have mentioned before. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @smpa01 okay, this isn't a problem, you can bind all of classes with animations that you want, you need to change a query selector, for your case will work document.querySelectorAll('svg rect') check this :)

Comment: Many thanks, will try out and repot back in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

### Animation chaining: use the event [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event)

You can chain CSS animations by using a listener on this event. It will be triggered when an animation on an element has been completed (including animation delays). Alternatively, if you use `transitions`, you need to use the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) event.

### Basic workflow

Extract the animation properties into a separate class, e.g. `.animation`.

```css
#firstEl.animation {
  // your animation properties
}
#secondEl.animation {
  // your animation properties
}
// etc
```

```js
const firstEl = document.getElementById('#firstEl');
const secondEl = document.getElementById('#secondEl');
const thirdEl = document.getElementById('#thirdEl');

firstEl.classList.add('animation');
firstEl.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  // start the 2nd animation
  secondEl.classList.add('animation');
});
secondEl.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  // start the 3rd animation
  thirdEl.classList.add('animation');
});
// etc
```

### Example

Here is an example with chained animations (from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event#examples)):

```js
const animation = document.querySelector('p.animation');
const animationEventLog = document.querySelector('.animation-example>.event-log');
const applyAnimation = document.querySelector('.animation-example>button.activate');
let iterationCount = 0;

animation.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  animationEventLog.textContent = `${animationEventLog.textContent}'animation started' `;
});

animation.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
  iterationCount++;
  animationEventLog.textContent = `${animationEventLog.textContent}'animation iterations: ${iterationCount}' `;
});

animation.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  animationEventLog.textContent = `${animationEventLog.textContent}'animation ended'`;
  animation.classList.remove('active');
  applyAnimation.textContent = "Activate animation";
});

animation.addEventListener('animationcancel', () => {
  animationEventLog.textContent = `${animationEventLog.textContent}'animation canceled'`;
});

applyAnimation.addEventListener('click', () => {
  animation.classList.toggle('active');
  animationEventLog.textContent = '';
  iterationCount = 0;
  let active = animation.classList.contains('active');
  if (active) {
    applyAnimation.textContent = "Cancel animation";
  } else {
    applyAnimation.textContent = "Activate animation";
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 3rem;
}

.event-log {
  width: 25rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: .2rem;
  padding: .2rem;
}

.animation.active {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-example">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="animation">You chose a cold night to visit our planet.</p>
  </div>
  <button class="activate" type="button">Activate animation</button>
  <div class="event-log"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but there won't be any event listener in this in my case

Comment: What do you mean with that?